# Send message to users who registered by did not complete event X

Tags: firebase-analytics

I would like to send messages to users who registered 7 days ago, and have not made a purchase, as a reminder.
I have created the audience below.  My questions are :

1. Is it certain that the message will not be sent out right after the registration and that the evaluation period will be 7 days after the registration to make sure they haven't made a purchase?  Do I need to specify this anywhere?
2. When choosing the Scheduling settings for the message, if I choose "Daily" then will all users who qualify to receive this message get it at the next 12:00 (as of 7 days after they register)?

Thanks!

[The criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92pLl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your audience is correct. "In any 7 days period" doesn't mean "7 days ago". 
With your current settings, you will target any user that registers within the last 7 days (= also 2 days ago, 3 days ago...).
By choosing "Daily" all users in your audience will receive your message. But you can specify within the notification parameters that users can receive this notification only once.

I'm also trying to create audiences of users that performed an action X-days ago, so I can't tell you right now the best way to do it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dorismandu,

Thank you for your help. Please take a look at here- https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/a-crash-course-in-using-new-audiences.html
Super useful article on audiences. This is from the article: "if you wanted an audience of "Users who have completed 3 exercises in the last 7 days", you could create an audience of people who have completed 3 exercises in any 7 day period, set the membership duration to 7 days, and that will get you fairly close."

Also I figured that it's more flexible to specify audiences when sending out the notifications.